# How to complete a “USER_TASK” in zeebe client of version 1.1.0 stable?

Tags: zeebe

How to complete a “USER_TASK” in zeebe-client of version 1.1.0 stable?I can’t find a api that could requet the broke to complete a user-task.
Did I ignore something?
I’m a beginner. Please help me.
For example:
What shall I do,if want to complete the user task in client(java)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo48v.png)

Answer (score 2):

User task work similar to normal service tasks, you just need to specify the correct job type. The job type is in that case `io.camunda.zeebe:userTask`

You can read more about that in the docs https://docs.camunda.io/docs/reference/bpmn-processes/user-tasks/user-tasks/